# Can't display images inside a HTML file received from server in tinyMCE

Tags: java, angular, rest, tinymce

I am sending from Backend (a Java project) to Frontend (Angular) a HTML file using a GET service. The received file is then set at the content of my tinyMCE editor.
The file is diplayed correctly but the images inside it are not displayed.
My guess is that they are not displayed because tinyMCE does not know about them and I should provide an image list in tinyMCE configuration. The problem is that I don't know how to do it.

What I tried so far:

- 1. The Frontend is receiving the following HTML file:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <h2>HTML Image</h2>
     <img src=\"image_1.png\" alt=\"Trulli\" width=\"500\" height=\"333\">
     <img src=\"image_2.png\" alt=\"Trulli\">              
   </body>
</html>
```

- 2. The tinyMCE displays the content correctly except the images that are not found.
- 3. I tried to save image_1.png and image_2.png under the Editor Component but the editor is still not finding the images. i.e. of structure:

```
editor.component.html
editor.component.css
editor.component.spec.ts
editor.component.ts
image_1.png
image_2.png
```

The current configuration of tinyMCE is:

```
this.tinyMceConfig = {
      branding: false,
      plugins: ["advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern", "toc"],
      height: 550,
      paste_data_images: true,
      image_advtab: true,
      imagetools_toolbar: `
        rotateleft rotateright |
        flipv fliph | 
        editimage imageoptions`,
      importcss_append: !0,
      inline: false,
      menubar: "insert",
      toolbar: `
        insertText insertfile undo redo |
        toc | formateselect |
        bold italic underline strikethrough forecolor backcolor |
        alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify |
        bullist numlist outdent indent |
        link image | print preview media"
        removeformat`,
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;

        editor.on('init', ed => {
          ed.target.setContent(this.data.content);
          console.log('editor initialized');
        });
        editor.on('keyup change', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.data.content = content;
          this.onEditorContentChange.emit(content);
        });
      }
    };
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Images must be placed under `assets`. So the correct `src` is, e.g. `assets/image_1.png`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! Never thought about trying that.

Comment: Should I post an answer with an explanation?

Comment: I read something related to assets that by default src from img that is searching for images under the assets folder. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, pretty much yeah, see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular configuration file, `angular.json` let's you declare which static resources the compiler/packager must include in the bundle, via the `assets` key

```
"build": {
  "options": {
    ...
    "assets": [
      "src/main/webapp/assets",
      ...
```

You are free to choose folders or single files, which will be accessible from the relative path `assets` or the absolute path `/assets`. 
This is the correct way to bundle resources to be used in template.

You can read more at [docs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#asset-config).